# Checking whether a number is prime when encoded in unary/binary

Tags: algorithm, primes

The following algorithm checks whether a number is prime:

```
Given a number n,loop over all numbers smaller than n and check whether they divide n. 
If one of them divides n, answer no. Otherwise, answer yes.
```

Now, I have to analyse the number of division operations performed by the algorithm as a function of the length of its input in the following two cases:

1) The number is encoded in unary (i.e, 4 is 1111). How do I show that the number of divisions is polynomial?

2) The number is encoded in binary (i.e, 4 is 100). How do I show that the number of divisions is exponential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have `n` `1`'s strung together (notated `1^n`).  `n` is the length of our input, obviously.  We will divide all the integers from `11`, `111`, ... ,`1^(n-1)` into `1^n`.  How many numbers will you be dividing into `1^n`, as a function of `n`?  Is this a polynomial?

Note that it takes `log_2(x)` (log base 2 of `x`) bits to represent `x`, approximately, in binary.  Also note that we will be performing `x-2` divisions (`2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, ... , `x-1` will be divided into `x`).  So, for `log_2(x)` bits we use `x-2` divisions.  Suppose, instead, that we let `n` be the size of our input.  So we have `n = log_2(x)`.  How many divisions will we take, then, in terms of a function of `n`?

Comment: For the first one, we're dividing n-2 numbers, which is a polynomial. For the binary situation, isn't it still n-2?

Comment: @SorinCioban in binary the number of digits is our problem size. `n` digits encode `2^n` magnitude value.

Comment: @SorinCioban What is your definition of `n` in the binary situation: the number of bits of the input or the magnitude of the number?

Comment: Yes, but we don't divide n to all the 2^n numbers, do we? We only divide them to the numbers that are smaller than n in both cases.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Suppose `x` is the magnitude.  It takes `log_2(x)` bits to represent `x` in base 2.  Let `f(x)` be the number of divisions we have to do to `x`. `f(x) = x-2` divisions, namely, `2`, `3`, `...` , `x-1`.  However our input is `log_2(x)` bits, which we will say is `n`.  So if `f(x) = x-2`, and `n = log_2(x)`, then `x = 2^n`.  You should be able to figure out `f(n)`, now, which will represent the number of divisions you need to do on an input of size `n` bits.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is frustrating; I'm just trying to guide you to you figuring out the answer and understanding why; I think you got it now, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Define the problem size `n` as being the number of digits in the (binary|unary) representation of the number.

Now consider how many different numbers you can encode in `n` digits.

Comment: For the given example...4 in unary = 1111; in 4 digits we can only encode one number; in binary, in 4 digits we can encode 15 numbers. But we won't be dividing by the ones that are higher than our current one, so isn't the number of divisions = givenNumber-2 either way?